# Strapi error: "Unexpected end of JSON input"

Tags: strapi, dotenv

I am trying to add **strapi-provider-upload-google-cloud-storage** to strapi project but getting an error when app started:

> Invalid json environment variable GCS_SERVICE_ACCOUNT: Unexpected end of JSON input

- OS: Windows
- Strapi version: 3.6.2

Answer (score 0):

1. Open .env file
2. Remove all the line break and spaces from *GCS_SERVICE_ACCOUNT*'s value.

Be aware there are issues when working with Strapi on windows besides the mentioned problem.